# Do calculations with users input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do simple calculations with a new value in an updated state. I'm simply trying to divide a users input, with another number. I am a total beginner, so forgive me for the rooky question! Here's my code which isn't working for me. There are no errors, it's just not showing the resulting figure from the calculation -

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Counter = () => {
  const [area, setArea] = useState("");
  const newArea = () => {
    setArea(area.target.value);
  };
  const deckBoards = (newArea) => {
    (newArea / 0.145).toFixed(2);
  };
  return (
    <div label="Deck">
      <h2>Total area of deck</h2>
      Area
      <input
        placeholder="Enter area here"
        type="text"
        onChange={newArea}
        type="number"
      />
      <br />
      <h2>Deck boards</h2>Deck boards at 140mm wide : {deckBoards} lineal metres
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `event` in the `newArea` function and `DeckBoards` needs to be `area` in JSx

Try this

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const Counter = () => {
  const [area, setArea] = useState("");
  const deckBoards = (newArea) => {
    // it was missing return statement
    return (newArea / 0.145).toFixed(2);
  };
  const newArea = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    // Calculate here
    const calculated = deckBoards(value);
    // Update value
    setArea(calculated);
  };
 
  
  return (
    <div label="Deck">
      <h2>Total area of deck</h2>
      Area
      <input
        placeholder="Enter area here"
        type="text"
        onChange={newArea}
        type="number"
      />
      <br />
      <h2>Deck boards</h2>Deck boards at 140mm wide : {area} lineal metres
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks so much!